# Eclipse no longer starts

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, fedora

Eclipse has been working fine for as long as I can remember but now it refuses to start.

The log file in the workspace shows the following. I am using Fedora 18.
Any ideas?

```
!SESSION 2013-03-17 20:16:47.631 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.2.0.M20130304-1457
java.version=1.7.0_09-icedtea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_AU
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-03-17 20:16:55.304
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.sac.CSSDocumentHandlerImpl.endDocument(CSSDocumentHandlerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.batik.css.parser.Parser.parseStyleSheet(Parser.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.dom.parsers.AbstractCSSParser.parseStyleSheet(AbstractCSSParser.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.parseStyleSheet(AbstractCSSEngine.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.setTheme(ThemeEngine.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.setTheme(ThemeEngine.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.setTheme(ThemeEngine.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.restore(ThemeEngine.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1179)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:945)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1423)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to eclipse folder path in command prompt(shell)
Run command eclipse -clean

Or

Delete old workbench(First copy all project present inside it). 
Start Eclipse.

Comment: Deleting the old workbench did nothing but eclipse -clean fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: eclipse -clean worked for me also, but not deleting the old workbench.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was Liferay Developer Studio, Which is essentially an Eclipse bundled with Liferay Plugins. It would try to load the workspace and would give me an error message - Could not load workspace, Please check the log file at (workspace location).

I tried starting it with -clean and also tried commenting the line responsible for error in `configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info` as suggested in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784169/installed-a-plugin-on-eclipse-mars-now-eclipse-wont-start-how-can-i-uninsta). At last, I found this post and followed Sach's answer.

I renamed my "workspace" to "workspace-copy" and started eclipse with "workspace", which it couldn't find and created a new one for me. The eclipse started successfully this time. I switched to the "workspace-copy" and it loaded fine as well. Voila! Problem solved. And then I went to Eclipse Marketplace to check my new plugin and it crashed. Oops, not too fast ameego. I then deleted "workspace" and started eclipse with "workspace" and it opened fine, just like the last time. Went into Eclipse Marketplace and uninstalled the newly installed plugins (Memory Analyzer). Switched the workspace to "workspace-copy" and it is working fine now. Pheww!! There goes my precious 3 hours..

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post my eperience as a comment so posting it here. Hope it helps a needy!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your workspace folder and delete .metadata. Then try to run eclipse. It will load into the workspace perfectly, creating a new .metada folder, as it was the first time running, with a blank workspace. Just import again your projects and it all will run.